# How can I get a CSS margin to overlap with CSS padding to avoid redundant spacing?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a wrapping `<div>` mean to add a border around something. It has a padding of 19px. Inside that wrapping `<div>` I want to insert pretty much any kind of content. Currently, it has another `<div>` inside. The problem is that that internal `<div>` has a bottom margin of 20px, so there is a space of 39px between the end of the internal `<div>` and the border, which just looks awkward.

As far as the question is concerned the relevant code is just

```
<div style="padding: 19px;">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

I just want to know how I can make the margin of the inner div overlap the padding of the outer div (or alternatively be set to zero by CSS acting on the class of the outer div).

Is there a way to make the bottom margin of the last item in the wrapper overlap with the padding? Alternatively, could I simply set the margin of the last child of the wrapper to 0px?

Comment: You need pseudo selectors. `div:last-child { your CSS }` Give the parent div an id and then just use `#parentDivsID div:last-child { margin-bottom:0px }`

Comment: Jay, that is basically what I just set up for now (except without the div qualifier because I want it to work for any tag, not just divs). See the "answer" I just posted. I would like to know if there is a way to make the margin and padding actually overlap though. I know CSS already does this when two margins would create redundant spacing (overlapping the margins, that is).

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out a way that seems to work for the alternative option (setting the bottom margin of the last child of the wrapper to 0px). Here's the relevant CSS where "callout-box" is the class of the wrapper.

```
.callout-box > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I'm still curious if there's a way to actually cause the margin and padding to overlap without removing the margin. In this case, there is a 1px difference since the solution I just gave sets the spacing to 19px whereas overlapping the margin and padding would give 20px.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to know how I can make the margin of the inner div overlap the padding of the outer div (or alternatively be set to zero by CSS acting on the class of the outer div).

Answer:

Very simple just add negative `top margin`. Look at the code below.

```
<div style="padding: 19px;">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top:-19px;">Inner Div</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for at all. I want to add CSS to the outer div that works for any HTML content inside (regardless of what it is) to remove the redundant spacing added at the bottom. If I was going to edit the style of the inner tag, it would be to remove the bottom margin, not mess with the top margin.

I get the feeling you didn't read the first paragraph at all.

Comment: The answer was based on your comments which you mentioned in this way "As far as the question is concerned the relevant code is just `<div style="padding: 19px;"><div style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div></div>` I just want to know how I can make the margin of the inner div overlap the padding of the outer div (or alternatively be set to zero by CSS acting on the class of the outer div)." Whereas you main question was confusing.